# Unable to adjust display brightness in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: brightness, amd-graphics

I use an HP laptop with an AMD R7-5800U CPU and Ubuntu 18.04, and I can't adjust display brightness with kernel versions **5.4** or **5.10.3**.

I also tried other solutions, including adjust the brightness in `/sys/class/backlight`, and in this path, there is a directory named as `api_video0`.

When I change the brightness from settings, the brightness in this path is changed while the screen brightness didn't change at all.

Comment: What is the model of the notebook? Some machines need to have an extra setting applied to a few files …

Comment: https://www.hpstore.cn/hp-66-g4-14-35f14pc.html

Comment: it's the latest hp laptop in China with the latest AMD R7-5800U cpu. I found similar problems in previous 5600u cpu and it can be solved with linux kernel 5.4.

Comment: In other words - when changing brightness levels, the file `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` changes the value written inside but the actual physical brightness does not change?

Comment: Can you please add the result of `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness` ?

Comment: yes, when changing brightness levels, the file /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness changes the value written inside but the actual physical brightness does not change.

Comment: `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/max_brightness` , the result is 99

Comment: Is it possible that the new ubuntu system doesn't have proper driver for the new graphic card in new AMD 5800U cpu? And I search driver in AMD website. There is only a windows version driver.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with the same laptop. I tried 20.04, 20.10, but none of them works. Also the USB-C and hdmi doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem common with Nvidia cards. If you do have an Nvidia video card, you are going to need to load the driver.

First of all do a `uname -a`, it will show something like `4.15.0-142-generic`, not exactly that, but something like that in the output.

After that do
`sudo apt install linux-headers-4.15.0-142 linux-headers-4.15.0-142-generic`.
It's not going to be that exact version, but the numbers have to match whatever `uname -a` gave you.

Then you are going to add the graphics driver repository:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

Now you can check what driver is available:
`sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`

It should display a list and some entry is going to say "recommended" next to it. So you can go ahead and install it.
`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Make sure to reboot and you should be all set. All that said, I really do hope that somebody fixes the issue that linux-headers packages are never part of any dependencies even though you can't load the video drivers correctly without them. 16.04 had a huge problem where it lost its mind every time the kernel updated. Every time there was a kernel update, before rebooting had to remember to go in and manually install the correct header set. Otherwise pain was inevitable.